# Разделение числа на разряды js

Tags: javascript, числа

есть функция которая выводит определенное значение от 5000 до 1000000 на сайте

Как сделать чтоб число выводилось разбитое на разряды, тоесть с пробелами 1 000 000

Сделал таким способом, не работает (((

```js
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}

// Basic Slider 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1000,
    min: 5000,
    max: 1000000,
    step: 1000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val($("#slider").numberWithSpaces(slider("value")));
});



//Advance Range Slider 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var getOutput = $("#state");
  var getSlider = $("#advance_slide");

  getSlider.slider({
    range: true,
    min: 5000,
    max: 1000000,
    values: [300, 500],
    step: 1000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      getOutput.html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
      $("#minValue").val(ui.values[0]);
      $("#maxValue").val(ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  getOutput.html(getSlider.slider("values", 0) + ' - ' + getSlider.slider("values", 1));
  $("#minValue").val(getSlider.slider('values', 0));
  $("#maxValue").val(getSlider.slider('values', 1));

});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <!-- Start slider -->
  <h1 class="text-center"> </h1>
  <label for="amount">Select Price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control" readonly="" style="font-weight: bold;color: green;margin-bottom: 15px">

  <div id="slider"></div>
  <!-- End slider -->
  <br/><br/>
  <hr/>

</div>
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16637051/6677992

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**Перевод**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16637051/6677992)

### 1. С помощью функций конвертации в строку.

```js
var num = 1234567890;
var result = num.toLocaleString();
console.log(result);

num = 1234567890.56;
result = num.toLocaleString();
console.log(result);
```

---

### 2. С помощью регулярных выражений.

Для целочисленных значений:

```js
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}
console.log(numberWithSpaces(1));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(100));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(10000));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(1000000));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(100000000));
```

Для значений с плавающей точкой:

```js
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
  var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
  return parts.join(".");
}
console.log(numberWithSpaces(1.05));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(100.05));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(10000.05));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(1000000.05));
console.log(numberWithSpaces(100000000.05));
```

Простые регулярные выражения. Можете узнать о них подробно [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Если вы не знаете изначально с каким типом значений будете работать- используйте второй вариант.

Comment: попробовал с помощью регулярок не работает (((

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо вставлять разреженные по-разрядно числа не в слайдер, а в отдельно созданный элемент!
До тех, пока вы будете вставлять непонятную для слайдера субстанцию в слайдер, он будет падать.
Вот этот слайдер юзай - http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/, модифицировать на порядок проще плюс требуемая задача там есть в примерах.

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
// В России в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части используется запятая, а в качестве разделителя разрядов - пробел
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(number));
// → 123 456,789
```

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)